# Is this function well-defined for all $\epsilon \in [0,1]$?

Tags: calculus

Let

$$f(\epsilon)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\{k\le i^\epsilon: k |i\} \right|}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\{k |i\} \right|}$$

Where $| \cdot |$ denotes cardinality of a set.

Obviously we have $f(0)=0$, $f(0.5)=0.5$ and $f(1)=1$. But is this function well-defined for all $\epsilon \in [0, 1]$?

Edit: it also seems like $f(1-\epsilon)=1-f(\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon \in [0,1]$ such that $f(\epsilon)$ is well-defined.

Comment: I believe it is true that $f(1/2)=1/2$ as you say, since if $ab=i$ then $a<\sqrt{i} \implies b>\sqrt{i}$. But there may be some pesky detail about showing perfect squares do not contribute significantly to the limit.

Comment: @Michael -- both sums are in $\Omega (n)$. The contribution of perfect squares is in $O(\sqrt n)$, so it becomes vanishingly small as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I don't see how it could fail to be well-defined; you have an unambiguous definition right there. (Well, the ambiguous part is $|\{k|i\}|$, which is not the clearest notation, but I think it would be too much to say "the function is not well-defined because it's unclear what  $|\{k|i\}|$ means".) Are you asking if the limit exists?

Comment: @MishaLavrov -- yup, I'm asking whether or not the limit exists

Comment: Really nice question! It's not hard to show $f$ is symmetric about $x=1/2$. Let $d(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n$ and $d_x(n)$ be the number of divisors less than $n^x$.  Note that $d > n^x$ implies $n/d \leq n^{1-x}$. So, $d(n) - d_x(n) = d_{1-x}(n)$.  Summing gives then gives $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 
d(i) - d_x(i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}d(i)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n d_{1-x}(i)}{{\sum_{i=1}^{n}d(i)}}$ and so $1-f(x) = f(1-x)$ whenever $f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit always exists, and $f(\epsilon)=\epsilon$.

Call the numerator

$$ A(\epsilon,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big|\{ k \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq k \leq i^\epsilon \land k \mid i \}\Big| $$

If $\delta: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the divisibility characteristic

$$ \delta(k,n) = \begin{cases} 1 & k \mid n \\ 0 & k \not\mid n \end{cases} $$

then

$$ A(\epsilon,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor i^\epsilon \rfloor} \delta(k,i) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor} \sum_{i=\lceil k^{1/\epsilon}\rceil}^n \delta(k,i) $$

$$ A(\epsilon,n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor} \left( \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{\lceil k^{1/\epsilon} \rceil-1}{k}\right\rfloor \right) $$

Using the fact that if $x \leq y$ and $z>0$
$$ \left\lfloor \frac{y-x}{z} \right\rfloor \leq \left\lfloor \frac{y}{z} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{z} \right\rfloor \leq \left\lceil \frac{y-x}{z} \right\rceil, $$

$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n-\lceil k^{1/\epsilon} \rceil+1}{k} \right\rfloor &\leq A(\epsilon,n) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor} \left\lceil\frac{n-\lceil k^{1/\epsilon} \rceil+1}{k}\right\rceil \\
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor} \frac{n-k^{1/\epsilon}-k}{k} &\leq A(\epsilon,n) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor} \frac{n-k^{1/\epsilon}+k+1}{k} \\
-\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor + \int_1^{n^\epsilon} \frac{n-x^{1/\epsilon}}{x} dx &\leq A(\epsilon,n) \leq n + \lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor + \int_1^{n^\epsilon} \frac{n+1-x^{1/\epsilon}}{x} dx
\end{align*} $$
For a general decreasing function, the upper limit of the left integral would be $\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor + 1$, but in this case instead it can stop before the integrand becomes negative. On the right, increasing the integral's upper limit only relaxes the inequality.

$$ -\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor + n \ln(n^\epsilon) - \epsilon(n - 1) \leq A(\epsilon,n) \leq n + \lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor + (n+1)\ln(n^\epsilon) - \epsilon(n-1)
 $$

The denominator in the original limit is $A(1,n)$, and

$$ \frac{-\lfloor n^\epsilon \rfloor + \epsilon(n \ln n - n + 1)}{(n+1)\ln n + n+1} \leq \frac{A(\epsilon,n)}{A(1,n)} \leq \frac{n + \lfloor n^\epsilon\rfloor + \epsilon((n+1)\ln n - n + 1)}{n \ln n -2n + 1} $$

Since $n \ln n$ is the dominant term, the limit squeezes to

$$ f(\epsilon) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A(\epsilon,n)}{A(1,n)} = \epsilon $$

(Note: Dirichlet proved the denominator $\sum_{i=1}^n \Big|\{k \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq k \leq i \land  k | i\}\Big|$ (Sloane's [A006218](http://oeis.org/A006218)) is $n (\ln n + 2 \gamma - 1) + O(\sqrt{n})$, but that much precision wasn't needed here.)